# Как написать код для расчета кратчайшего пути в схеме с расстояниями?

Tags: javascript

Только начал изучать JS и программирование вообще, пытаюсь написать код который будет искать в схеме кратчайший путь от a до с. Столкнулся с двумя проблемами:

1. как сделать, чтобы код адекватно работал если везде будут одинаковые расстояния?
2. если получилось сразу несколько кратчайших путей, как сделать чтобы их все можно было увидеть?

---

```
function raschetPuti(ab, bc, cd, da, ac, bd) {
    let korotki1
    let korotki2
    let korotki3
    let korotki4
    let korotki5
    const ba = ab
    const cb = bc
    const dc = cd
    const ad = da
    const ca = ac
    const db = bd
    if (ab < ad && ab < ac) {
       if (bd < bc) {
          const korotki1 = ab + bd + dc
           console.log('кратчайший путь a-b-d-c длиной', korotki1)
       }
        else {
            const korotki2 = ab + bc
            console.log('кратчайший путь a-b-c длиной', korotki2)
        }
    }
    else if (ac < ab && ac < ad) {
        const korotki3 = ac
        console.log('кратчайший путь a-c длиной', korotki3)
    }
    else if (ad < ac && ad < ab) {
        if (db < dc) {
            const korotki4 = ad+db+bc 
            console.log('кратчайший путь a-d-b-c длиной', korotki4)
        }
        else {
            const korotki5 = ad + dc
            console.log('кратчайший путь a-d-c длиной', korotki5)
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('не нашел')
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function raschetPuti(ab, bc, cd, da, ac, bd) {
    let korotki1
    let korotki2
    let korotki3
    let korotki4
    let korotki5
    const ba = ab
    const cb = bc
    const dc = cd
    const ad = da
    const ca = ac
    const db = bd
    if (ab < ad && ab < ac) {
       if (bd < bc) {
          const korotki1 = ab + bd + dc
           console.log('кратчайший путь a-b-d-c длиной', korotki1)
       }
        else {
            const korotki2 = ab + bc
            console.log('кратчайший путь a-b-c длиной', korotki2)
        }
    }
    else if (ac < ab && ac < ad) {
        const korotki3 = ac
        console.log('кратчайший путь a-c длиной', korotki3)
    }
    else if (ad < ac && ad < ab) {
        if (db < dc) {
            const korotki4 = ad+db+bc 
            console.log('кратчайший путь a-d-b-c длиной', korotki4)
        }
        else {
            const korotki5 = ad + dc
            console.log('кратчайший путь a-d-c длиной', korotki5)
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('не нашел')
    }
}
```

Comment: @SwaD `a -> c`, написано ж.

Comment: я что-то не понял, в вашей первой паре ифоф, заявляется что ab+bd+dc может быть коротким, пр этом длина dc вообще не фигурирует нигде в неравенствах

Comment: @teran видимо пора выключать все и спать идти..

Comment: у вас число всех путей, которые на схеме есть не велико. Просчитайте все, бует у вас путь->длина. Отсортируйте массив, по возрастанию, и выведите первые с одинаковым значением.

Comment: @teran, да, это тоже ошибка, я не включил его в неравенства потому что думал что там и так очевидно что если дойти до точки d то дальше кратчайший путь будет до c от нее, но ведь может быть и по другому. В общем, сложная задача, не знаю решаема ли вообще

Comment: у вас путей 4 штуки, вычислите их сразу все просуммировав величины отрезков. Сложите в массив, найдите минимум. Выведите все значения равные минимуму. Итого 4 строки на определение длин. Одна - сложить в массив. Первый цикл на максимум. Второй цикл на вывод.

Comment: @teran, звучит правильно для конкретно этой схемы, это самый простой путь по сути. А если добавить в схему еще несколько пунктов и расстояний? Тогда их будет уже нереально вручную просчитывать, нужен будет какой-то алгоритм который сделает это сам. В этом и смысл задачи, найти его

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Если добавить еще пунктов и расстояний, то схему начинаем называть взвешенным графом, пункты - вершинами, между вершинами - ребра, а из А в С у вас путь, если вдруг идти можно только в одну сторону по отрезку, то это направленный граф. Берем какое-нить учебное пособие для учащихся вузов по теории графов и изучаем. Там явно будут рассмотрены алгоритмы поиска кратчайшего пути.